# Regex match anything but a new line

Tags: r, regex

I have a text document where there is text above

SHOW: a given name of a show

More text below

I need a regular expression that just matches the "Show: a given name of a show" and that's it, please

I have tried `'SHOW:[^\n]+'` but I received more than just "Show: a given name of a show"

Comment: Your solution [is working](https://rextester.com/KAWG90839).

Comment: You can also use `strsplit(my_text,"\\n.*")`. It seems from your desired output that you need SHOW to change case, is this true?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse) 
string <- "Show: a given name of a show \n
      Show: a given name of a show"
str_extract_all(string =string, pattern = "Show:[:print:]+(?=(\n|$))")

> str_extract_all(string =string, pattern = "Show:[:print:]+(?=(\n|$))")
[[1]]
[1] "Show: a given name of a show " "Show: a given name of a show"
```

this could work